# Error while detecting faces and apply blur on them

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I'm creating an application that capture video stream via webcam and detect the faces and blur them

And this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



    int blur_value = 50;
    Mat src; Mat dst;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    bool read = true;
    char winName[] = "Blured WebCam";
    String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;


    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"Error while opening your webcam\n";
        return 0;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        cap.read(src);
        vector <Rect> faces;
        Mat blk;
        cvtColor( src, blk, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
        equalizeHist( blk, blk );

        face_cascade.detectMultiScale( blk, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

        for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
        {
             Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height/2 );

             blur( src, dst, Size( faces[i].width/2, faces[i].height/2), Point(-1,-1) );


        }


        imshow(winName, dst);

        switch(waitKey(10))
        {
        case 27:
            return 0;
        }


    }


    return 0;
}
```

There is no errors in the compilation process, the error comes in when i try to run the application

I got this error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in
>   imshow, file
>   /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 269 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Where is the problem?

Comment: The assertion tells you what the problem is. Use a debugger and backtrace it.

Comment: If you don't get any face at the first frame, then `dst` won't be initialized and your `imshow` fails because you're showing an empty image. When `faces.empty()` you should show `src`, or adjust your logic

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting that error when there are no faces detected. If `imshow` is called on empty frame, it'll give an error. Try this as @miki has suggested

```
if(!faces.empty()) {
  imshow(winName, dst);
}
```